# Update a value on redux form

Tags: react-redux, react-bootstrap, redux-form

I have a react-bootstrap class of a form. The code is something like that:

```
class MyReactClass extends Component {

// ....

render() {

    return (
        <div>

<Field name="combobox1" component={ComboBox} options={options} ></Field>
<Field name="textField2" component={My_TextField}></Field>
<Field name="textField3" component={My_TextField}></Field>
<Field name="textField4" component={My_TextField}></Field>
       </div>
   }
}


export default reduxForm({
    form: 'myReactClass ',
  }
)(MyReactClass );
```

I added an initialization to initialize some values:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.initialize({textField2:'blabla'});
  }
```

Now I want that when the user selects a value from the combobox, it'll automatically change the value of textfield3. I have a WORKING onChange function for the combobox, but I can't find a way to change textfield3's value. I tried to use "initialize" again -
 this.props.initialize({textField3: this.getUpdatedValue()});
but it initialize the whole form and the form gets cleared and have only the value for textfield3.

I tried to access `this.props.textField3` but I got `undefined`.

**How can I update the form's value?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props.change('textField3', this.getUpdatedValue())` would work.

Optionally, if you need the user to understand that the value was autofilled but can be manually changed, you can use:

`this.props.autofill('textField3', this.getUpdatedValue())`

These are described in the docs [here](http://redux-form.com/6.3.1/docs/api/Props.md/).

Comment: what's the different between autofill and change in this case? How does the user understand that he can manually change the value?